# Need assistance with window.onload and IE

Tags: php, javascript

I currently have a table of email templates.  The user is able to click the template, and populate the email template field pending on the td that gets clicked.  I have a JS script that works fine in FF, but not in IE.

The following is JUST pseudocode of my php for timesake.

```
$somevar = mysql_query("...");
while (($anothervar = mysql_fetch_assoc($somevar))) {
    echo '<tr><td class="test">'.$email['email_name'].'</td><tr>';
}
```

Here is the current JS I have that only works in FF.

```
function getName(e) {
    $('input[name="Clear Button"]').click(function () {
        $('span').text('');
    });
    var cell = e.target;
    cell = cell.innerHTML;
    if (window.XMLHttpRequest) { // code for IE7+, Firefox, Chrome, Opera, Safari
        xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
    } else { // code for IE6, IE5
        xmlhttp = new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
    }
    xmlhttp.onreadystatechange = function () {
        if (xmlhttp.readyState == 4 && xmlhttp.status == 200) {
            document.getElementById("test").innerHTML = xmlhttp.responseText;
        }
    }
    xmlhttp.open("GET", "/includes/adminPages/Update_Email.inc.php?selection_id=" + cell, true);
    xmlhttp.send();
}


window.onload = function () {
    var cells = document.getElementsByClassName("test");
    for (var i = 0, len = cells.length; i < len; i++) {
        cells[i].onclick = getName;
    }
};
```

Just for the record, I did take a look at the following example, but that did not solve my problem.

```
window.onload = new function() { alert('hello');};
```

Comment: What error do you see in the console? Try replacing `e.target` by `e.target || e.srcElement`

Comment: @plalx I'm not necessarily seeing an error.  What is happening *I think* is that it's not handling the window.onload() line correctly.  I tried using an alert to validate my assumption.  The conclusion that is only part of the issue.

Comment: @Matt I am currently using IE 9

Comment: Have you tried following the execution of your script in IE's developer tools (open them clicking F12)?

Comment: @CBC_NS, Well it's hard to debug without any test case in place for us. `window.onload = function () {};` is a valid way of registering a load event handler in IE9, even tough you should be using `addEventListener`, so it's not the issue. Have you checked if you enter the `onload` handler and if you are entering the `onclick` handler?

Comment: It looks like you're using jQuery, if you suspect that `window.onload` isn't working as intended, have you tried using `$(document).ready(function() {});`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I see you're using jQuery, so maybe let's rewrite it

```
$(window).on('load', function() {
    $('.test').on('click', function() {

        var id = $(this).html();

        $.get("/includes/adminPages/Update_Email.inc.php?selection_id=" + id, function(data) {
            $('#test').html(data);
        });
    });
});
```